# AWS Lambda early timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a lambda which is behind a private API Gateway endpoint in a VPC. It is set to timeout in 15 minutes, but every call to it is timing out in 15 seconds.

I know that the max timeout for the API Gateway endpoint itself is 29 seconds, but I can't for the life of me find where the 15 second limit is coming from.

Does anyone have any input on why a lambda with a 15 minute timeout behind an APIGW with a 29 second timeout is in fact timing out after 'just' 15 seconds?

Logs of an example of it timing out below. Only including the default lambda logs as custom logs contain sensitive info.

Note: Yes I realize that even 15 seconds is extremely long. I will be changing the process to an async one where a request is passed in and returned fairly quickly while the actual request is processed after the caller has gotten their return. But I really want to know what it is I am missing in my understanding of how Lambda should be working here.

````
START RequestId: 851a7dc4-2e7a-4a86-809c-ecaa41490e8a Version: 49

2024-01-09T15:47:59.379Z 851a7dc4-2e7a-4a86-809c-ecaa41490e8a Task timed out after 15.06 seconds

END RequestId: 851a7dc4-2e7a-4a86-809c-ecaa41490e8a

REPORT RequestId: 851a7dc4-2e7a-4a86-809c-ecaa41490e8a  Duration: 15060.86 ms   Billed Duration: 15000 ms   Memory Size: 256 MB Max Memory Used: 224 MB Init Duration: 1349.61 ms```
````

Comment: Do you have any logs from an invocation? When a Lambda doesn't behave as expected, that should be the first place you look.

Comment: Given the exactness of the timeout I have to ask - you're sure you did 15 *minutes*?

Comment: That's a fair question but yes I am sure. I also tried other values like 10 minutes and 5 minutes, but it still times out at 15 seconds. I also got others to check just to make sure I was reading the correct values and everyone agrees it is set to 15 minutes (or 10 or 5 when it was).

I imagine it something to do with the API GW lambda integratino, but the only value I can find to set there is the Integration Requests Settings timeout, which is at the default value of 29s.

I wish I had more info to provide but I just don't have anything beyond the fact it is timing but I don't

Comment: If it timed out at the configured max duration, there would be a "Task timed out" log in CW Logs. Otherwise, the code simply ran to completion.

Comment: You're invoking a specific version of the Lambda. So while the timeout configured for the `$LATEST` version might be 15 minutes, the timeout for that specific version (49) is likely to be 15 seconds.

Comment: And in the future, please edit your questions to provide additional detail. It's next to impossible to read code posted in a comment.

Comment: If the function version being invoked genuinely has 15m timeout but invocation is timing out at 15s, then I'd be tempted to configure x-ray, collect logs, and send them to AWS with a bug/support request.

Comment: Can you please provide your timeout configuration screenshot? Please note you need give timeout value in seconds. please provide 900

Comment: @kdgregory you were correct. It was calling a specific version of the lambda so my changes weren't having any effect. Thanks for the help. If you'd like to put in an answer I will accept it.